# NSfetch Request Returns The Same Data Always Not Returns the Updated Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am developing one iOS  Application using core data.I'm using Rest kit to connect with web services,With the help of rest kit i'm syncing the data from web service and storing in my local core database.It is working fine for me.When i will call the fetch request the data is getting in correct. But after some time i want the latest updated data from the web service, if i sync again the latest data is getting and replaced in my db correctly.

But if i try to fetch the latest data the fetch request returns the first data that saved in the data base. But if i restart my application the fetch request returns the updated data.What is the actual problem. I am new in iOS so i do not understand the problem.How I will solve the issue.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: @Timuçin which code fetch request code? or Data mapping code?

Comment: Are you using fetchedResultsController or simply fetchRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `NSFetchedResultsController`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;


 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [sef fetchAll];
 }


 // initialize and  fetch all data and also implements it's delgate

#pragma mark Fetch All Data from core data
 -(void)fetchAll
{
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SongInfo"];
   NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"songTitle" ascending:YES];
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];
   NSError *error = nil;

   // Setup fetched results
   self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:      [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
   [self.fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];
   BOOL fetchSuccessful = [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
   //    NSAssert([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count], @"Seeding didn't work...");
   if (! fetchSuccessful) {
    // RKTwitterShowAlertWithError(error);
   }

   if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]count ]==0) {
       // reload your table
   }
   else
   {

   }

}


  #pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

 - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  {
    [tbl relodaData];
    // reload your view here
  }
```

Comment: i am using fetch request in many places . Actually what is the difference between the nsfetch request and nsfetch request controller?

Comment: The fetched results controller delegate will be notified when content will be changed, giving the delegate the opportunity to animate the changes in the table view

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you are calling `context` `save` method correctly after syncing local database with the REST service.

If you are using fetchedResultsController, it may occur due to cached data. Try to clear the cached data to get the correctly updated data,

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

  if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
     return _fetchedResultsController;
  }

  // Clear cache
  [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Root"];

  // Your codes

}
```

Comment: i am not using fetchedResultsController.Just fetch request only.

Comment: First i written the context save function in app delegate but now add context save function in to my view controller and again checked no changes

Comment: @user3762713 If you are using REST Kit, the data from service will be storing using `mainQueueManagedObjectContext` of `RKManagedObjectStore`. right? Are you using the same context to fetch data?

Comment: I am using RKManagedObjectStore.Yes Same context to fetch the data.i checked my local data base using core data editor and make sure the updated data is in data base. And another thing is some times i am getting the updated data some times the old data in fetch request.